# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rows'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i want my program to print the five first characters when he recognize a string, made of the addition of two columns (from a dataframe made with pandas), in some lines of a .txt, but as it is said in the title, it gives me this error when i run the code. Here is the code (the important lines are in the end of the code, i just put everything if you want to see the whole code).

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

link = "excelfilett.txt"
file = open(link, "r")
frames_load = []
is_count_frames_load = False
for line in file:
    if "[Interface1]" in line:
        is_count_frames_load = True
    if is_count_frames_load== True:
        frames_load.append(line)
    if "[EthernetComNeed]" in line:
        break

number_of_rows_load = len(frames_load) -1
header_load = re.split(r'\t', frames_load[0])
number_of_columns_load = len(header_load)

frame_array_load = np.full((number_of_rows_load, number_of_columns_load), 0)
df_frame_array_load = pd.DataFrame(frame_array_load)
df_frame_array_load.columns= header_load

for row in range(number_of_rows_load):
    frame_row_load = re.split(r'\t', frames_load[row])
    for position in range(len(frame_row_load))

df_frame_array_load["[Name]"] = df_frame_array_load["[End1]"] + "  " +  df_frame_array_load["[End2]"]


link = "excelfilett.txt"
file = open(link, "r")
frames_path = []
is_count_frames_path = False
for line in file:
    if "[Routing Paths]" in line:
        is_count_frames_path = True
    if is_count_frames_path== True:
        for row in df_frame_array_load["[Name]"].rows:
            if row in line:
                print(line[0:4])
    if "[EthernetComConfig]" in line:
        break
```

It gives me the AttributeError on "for row in df_frame_array_load["[Name]"].rows:" and it shoudln't be a version error, what is the problem then? I don't understand.

Comment: Pandas.Series indeed has no attribute "rows" in the latest 0.23.4 version of pandas. (I don't know if it had attribute "rows" before).

Comment: Indeed, i thought they were an rows attribute on the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for row in df_frame_array_load["[Name]"].rows:
```

because pandas Series object does not have a "rows" attribute, as you for perform a perform a loop operation in a `Series` you are iterating over it.

should be changed to just:

```
for row in df_frame_array_load["[Name]"]:
    ...
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, i don't remember where i saw this, but i thought that pandas had a row attribute.